# Handling string out of range exception

Tags: java

I am doing a very basic loop through a file. The file contains a number of entries, however, it seems to break after the 3rd loop which definately contains more than 25 characters. The simple loop is as follows:

```
public static void organiseFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String directory = "C:\\Users\\hussainm\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1";
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(directory + "_temp.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(directory + "_ordered.txt");
        while (fileIn.hasNextLine() == true) {
            if (!fileIn.nextLine().isEmpty()) {

                lines.add(fileIn.nextLine());
                String test = fileIn.nextLine().substring(12, 25);
                System.out.println(test);
            }
        }
```

I am not sure what the issue is, but it keeps throwing:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 25     at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   fedOrganiser.fedOrganiser.organiseFile(fedOrganiser.java:41)  at
>   fedOrganiser.fedOrganiser.main(fedOrganiser.java:31)

Not sure what its issue is.

File is as follows:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/69h1f8u387zikbp/ex1_temp.txt?dl=0

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of the file you try to read.

Comment: Check your C:\\Users\\hussainm\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1_temp.txt file. Check every line is 25 chars long or not ?

Comment: You also call nextLine() 3 times each time you check if the file has one next line. nextLine() returns the **next** line, every time you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Every call to `nextLine()` reads the next line from the stream.  It is `nextLine()`, not `hasNextLine()`, which advances the stream one line's worth of text.  You are reading 3 lines per loop.

When calling `nextLine` for the first time in a loop, assign it to a variable and refer to that variable for the rest of the loop.

```
String line = fileIn.nextLine();
if (!line.isEmpty()) {
    lines.add(line);
    String test = line.substring(12, 25);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Incidentally, there is no need to compare a `boolean` such as what is returned by `hasNextLine()` to `true`.  Just use the `boolean` itself, e.g.:

```
while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
```

Comment: Doh! I just noticed. Thanks for this :)

Comment: All true but the exception is thrown because the parsed line is of less than 25 chars.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming every line has at least 25 characters in it with the line:

```
String test = fileIn.nextLine().substring(12, 25);
```

I'm guessing you have some lines that are shorter or blank.

Answer (score 0):

You'd check String `length()` before doing substrings.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `scanner.nextLine()` advances to the next line. You should do it like this, if you are sure that every line has at least 25 characters:

```
public static void organiseFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String directory = "C:\\Users\\hussainm\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1";
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(directory + "_temp.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(directory + "_ordered.txt");
        while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileIn.nextLine();
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {

                lines.add(line);
                String test = line.substring(12, 25);
                System.out.println(test);
            }
        }
...
}
```

What I do not understand is what you want to test with `line.isEmpty()` because this will be always true as long as there are lines. Even a seemingly empty line contains at least a line break.

Answer (score 0):

The exception will be thrown if the line you are parsing is of less than 25 chars long.

**Notes**

1. Not sure if your intent is to parse every 3 lines, but
   **fileIn.nextLine()** appear three time. So you are missing one line out of three.
   See [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()):

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped.

2. Maybe this is what you are trying to do:

   ```
       Scanner in = null;
       PrintWriter out = null;

       try {
           URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/test_in.txt");
           File file = new File(url.getFile());
           ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
           in = new Scanner(file);
           out = new PrintWriter("/test_out.txt");
           int lineNumber = 0;
           while (in.hasNextLine()) {
               String line = in.nextLine();
               lineNumber++;
               if (line != null && line.trim().length() > 0) {
                   lines.add(line);
                   String test = line.substring(12, line.length()<25?line.length():25);
                   System.out.println(String.format("line# %d: \t\"%s\"",  lineNumber, test));
               }
           }
           System.out.println(String.format("last line number: %d", lineNumber));
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           in.close();
           out.close();
       }
   ```

EDIT: For the completeness
[image]